# How to take a variable from a function in a javascript file, and display it with html in a seperate file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty sure this is a very basic question, yet dispite looking through the internet I cannot understand how to do it. Please note that today is my first time ever using javascript and I have very little idea in what I am doing.

Anyway, I have a HTML file and a Javascript file. The javascript file's purpose is to generate a random interger between 1 and 10. I have achieved this with a function which I will display with the rest of my code below. The idea is that with a button press, the function will activate and put it into a "div" tag. Then, the output should display underneath. The problem is I'm recieving no output. Here's a few chunks of my HTML code:

```
<head>
<script src="japanese.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="japanese.css">
</head>

<button onclick="random()">Random integer</button>
<br>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

And also my javascript code, in a seperate file:

```
function random() {
    var integer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10))) + 1;
    document.getElementById('result').value = integer;
}
```

Please just give me a straight up answer rather then redirecting me to a link.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is the js code you show in the japanese.js file?

Comment: the js code is in a seperate, js file.

Comment: include it in the hml file like you do for the japanese.js file

Comment: please explain what do you mean by include it, and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed out the closing bracket `)` right before `+`. And also to display the result in `div`, you should set the value in `innerText` or `innerHTML` property, `value` property is for `input`s.

```js
function random() {
    var integer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10))) + 1;
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = integer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="random()">Random integer</button>
<br>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

Comment: I Appreciate your time, but I in my actuall code I had all 3 brackets already so I probably missed the last one. Didn't think it could be so easily fixed!